# How to send a big array to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to send a several list (about 20000 id's) to a stored procedure, like this:

```
1391924, 6546510, 7419635, 6599910, 6546888, 1116510, 6546720, ...
```

I have this data on a `List<int>`

How can I do to send this list to an stored procedure?

And then I need to insert the id's list on a temporary table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use: [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Table-valued parameters are a new parameter type in SQL Server 2008. Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters.

Table-valued parameters are like parameter arrays in OLE DB and ODBC, but offer more flexibility and closer integration with Transact-SQL. Table-valued parameters also have the benefit of being able to participate in set-based operations.

Eg.:

**SQL Server:**

Create Table-Valued Parameters:

```
  CREATE TYPE IDsTableType AS TABLE
  (                     
        [Product] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
  )
```

Pass it to Stored Procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetIDs
 (
       @TableVariable IDsTableType READONLY
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
  //Do Something

 END
 GO
```

**C# Code for passing table valued parameter to Stored Procedure:**

```
DataTable dataTable = GetData();
// Configure the SqlCommand and SqlParameter.
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(
    "GetIDs", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@TableVariable", dataTable);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Refer: [Passing table-valued parameter data to a stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you write the array into a DataTable, you can [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) the DataTable into the database.  Then the stored proc could just read from that table.

Comment: You can even bulk insert without a data table. I regularly bulk insert directly from objects. All you need is an IDataReader implementation for objects - generics thank you for that not being hard.