# How to bind an Array Parameter (Stored Procedure) via Native ODBC

Tags: c, sql-server, windows, stored-procedures, odbc

I've been looking for a way to pass an array of integers to a stored procedure via the ODBC API in C / C++. While there is `VARCHAR(XX)` as array type of characters,  there is no array type for integers, such as `VARINT(XX)` or something like that.

Many answers (e.g. [How to send a big array to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14648043/2334932) ) suggest using **Table-Valued Parameters**. However they all use *C# / ADO.NET, Java or PHP* code with types which are simply not available in the C ODBC API.

My stored procedure:

```
-- "Array" Parameter type, used in the stored procedure later on
CREATE TYPE dbo.CharList
AS TABLE (Id INT)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Character_Nation]
    @OldNation_Id   INT,
    @NewNation_Id   INT,
    @Excluded       dbo.CharList READONLY, -- array / table parameter
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Characters
    SET Nation_Id = @NewNation_Id
    WHERE Nation_Id = @OldNation_Id AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @ExcludedChars) -- parameter used to exclude result sets here
END
```

So I've tried several things:

**1. Passing the array directly**

```
void UpdateCharacterNationTestArray()
{
    unsigned int old_nation_id = 2;
    unsigned int new_nation_id = 4;

    unsigned int excluded_character_ids[] = {24, 36};
    SQLLEN arr_size = ARRAYSIZE(excluded_character_ids);
    SQLINTEGER cb = SQL_NTS;

    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &old_nation_id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &new_nation_id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, arr_size, 0, excluded_character_ids, 0, &cb); // Binding array directly, like one would do with a VARCHAR type

    SQLRETURN res = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call dbo.Update_Character_Nation(?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if (res != SQL_SUCCESS && res != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        printf("Error during query execution: %hd\n", res);
        ProcessLogs(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    }
}
```

This fails with the diagnostic record:

> ERROR; native: 206; state: 22018; msg: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with
>   CharList

**2. Passing the array as Table-Valued Parameter** (or at least trying to do so)

```
void UpdateCharacterNationTestTVP()
{
    unsigned int old_nation_id = 2;
    unsigned int new_nation_id = 4;

    unsigned int excluded_character_ids[] = {24, 36};
    SQLLEN arr_size = ARRAYSIZE(excluded_character_ids);
    SQLINTEGER cb = SQL_NTS;
    SQLCHAR* tvp_name = (SQLCHAR*)"dbo.CharList";

    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &old_nation_id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &new_nation_id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DEFAULT, SQL_SS_TABLE, arr_size, 0, tvp_name, 0, &cb); // Binding the type here. All parameters after SQL_PARAM_INPUT are taken from MSDN documentation about TVP

    // Super scary binding stuff tvp requires you to do
    SQLINTEGER cb_rows[] = {SQL_NTS, SQL_NTS};
    SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_SOPT_SS_PARAM_FOCUS, (SQLPOINTER)3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);  // focusing the third parmeter (the TVP one) for the call(s) below
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, arr_size /*or 0*/, 0, excluded_character_ids, sizeof(UINT), cb_rows); // binding of the actual array in a column styled fashion here
    SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_SOPT_SS_PARAM_FOCUS, (SQLPOINTER)0, SQL_IS_INTEGER);  // resetting the focus

    SQLRETURN res = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call dbo.Update_Character_Nation(?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if (res != SQL_SUCCESS && res != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        printf("Error during query execution: %hd\n", res);
        ProcessLogs(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    }
}
```

This code (copied off this MSDN article more or less: [Use Table-Valued Parameters (ODBC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-how-to/use-table-valued-parameters-odbc) ) errors out with:

> ERROR; native: 0; state: 07002; msg: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

**3. ?**

I'm ultimately looking for a way to call a stored procedure with an array of unsigned integers. If there is a another way of doing that, please advise. If possible, I'd like to stay away from string (VARCHAR) parsing though.

**Environment**

For visibility I have not included the ODBC initialization code however these are the environment specs:

- Visual Studio 2013
- SQL Server 2014
- ODBC Version: `SQL_OV_ODBC3`
- Driver Connection: TCP/IPv4
- `hstmt` = allocated SQL statement handle
- C++ (the code however is not making use of C++ language features, hence 100% C compatible)

Any ideas on the approaches above or a completely new suggestion on how to bind an array as stored procedure parameter is appreciated.

Comment: It's been ages since I touched ODBC, but: 1) cb = SQL_NTS seems wrong as they use it for the actual number of rows 2) passing parameter name is not necessary as they are bound by position 3) passing SQL_NTS to cb_rows seems wrong too but they are likely ignored for ordinal types.

Comment: It is quite amazing to see someone still using ODBC.

Comment: Thanks for the short thoughts about this. You are right about your first and second point. The `SQLBIndParameter` call which binds the TVP column needs the `cb` value to be set to the **actual amount of available rows**. Then leaving the TVP name out in this binding call works as well :)
OT: I think a noticeable amount of people still use native ODBC because of the lack of alternatives for native Win32 programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging deeper, I found out that the first ODBC API call failing is actually the binding call for the TVP column / parameter:

```
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DEFAULT, SQL_SS_TABLE, arr_size, 0, tvp_name, 0, &cb);
```

This call returns `SQL_ERROR` and checking the diagnostic record issued by this gave me the following error:

> HY004 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type

This specific issue was asked here already but sadly remained unsolved. Ultimately **using an outdated ODBC driver** was the cause of this whole problem. See my answer on another question for more details on how to fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113255/2334932

Then two points brought up by @A.K. in his comment finally solved the issue:

**1. Parameter Length**

The last value passed to `SQLBindParameter`, the parameter length or `cb` here, needed to have **actual amount of available rows** rather than `SQL_NTS`, as it is used as input parameter here.

**2. Passing the parameter name is not necessary as they are bound by position**

I think it will work with or without, but specifying the name of the TVP here is actually not necessary and can be left out.

So changing the third `SQLBindParameter` call to this fixed the rest of the issue(s):

```
cb = arr_size;
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DEFAULT, SQL_SS_TABLE, arr_size, 0, NULL, 0, &cb);
```

**Full working code**

```
void UpdateCharacterNationTestTVP()
{
    unsigned int old_nation_id = 2;
    unsigned int new_nation_id = 4;

    unsigned int excluded_character_ids[] = {24, 36};
    SQLLEN arr_size = ARRAYSIZE(excluded_character_ids);
    SQLINTEGER cb = arr_size; // Needs to have the actual amount of available rows

    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &old_nation_id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &new_nation_id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DEFAULT, SQL_SS_TABLE, arr_size, 0, NULL, 0, &cb); // Does not need the name of the TVP

    // Super scary binding stuff tvp requires you to do
    SQLINTEGER cb_rows[] = {SQL_NTS, SQL_NTS};
    SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_SOPT_SS_PARAM_FOCUS, (SQLPOINTER)3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);  // focusing the third parmeter (the TVP one) for the call(s) below
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, arr_size /*or 0*/, 0, excluded_character_ids, sizeof(UINT), cb_rows); // binding of the actual array in a column styled fashion here
    SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_SOPT_SS_PARAM_FOCUS, (SQLPOINTER)0, SQL_IS_INTEGER);  // resetting the focus

    SQLRETURN res = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call dbo.Update_Character_Nation(?,?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if (res != SQL_SUCCESS && res != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        printf("Error during query execution: %hd\n", res);
        ProcessLogs(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option may be to parse your array into a delimited list and pass it through to the procedure.

There is an excellent answer for how to do that, with references to other sites, etc on the below question:

[T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)

Comment: There indeed are multiple (ugly) ways of doing it. Even the first solution your linked answer proposes is using TVP as "probably the closest to a universal "best" approach", which brings me back to the issue I'm having here. However, I was able to fix this issue by now. See my answer below. Thanks